# Enable user interaction of a button SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiview, ibaction, user-interaction

OK, so lets assume the button created below is greyed out and user interaction disabled.

How do I enable the button from anywhere else.

I know how to disable the button from inside the button function, sender.enabled = false, but I don't want to disable it from there.

I want to re-enable the user interaction from outside the button function.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func loadButton(sender: UIButton) {
      //i wan to enable interaction of this button via override func and         NSUserDefaults
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS and OS X development you have so-called `outlets` that are variables pointing to UI elements. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Outlet.html).

To declare an outlet, you prefix your variable with `@IBOutlet` like so:

`@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!`

and then you need to connect your outlet to the button in your `xib` file. That can be done in several ways, but if you have declared a variable like the above, you can:

1. go to your storyboard
2. in the document outline hold down the control button
3. while holding down the control button, you drag from your `files owner` or `ViewController` to the `UIButton` you'd like to connect to
4. select the outlet you'd like to connect to (`button` in this case)

As shown here

[image: One way to connect an outlet]

Once that is in place, you are free to use enable your button (and much more) in your code, for instance:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.enabled = false
}
```

You can read more about IBOutlets [here](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)

And here is [another way to connect outlets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) (this is how I prefer to connect outlets actually, you define and connect in one go)

Hope that helps

Comment: You're welcome. Outlets is a bit odd when you start out in iOS or OS C development but once you learn the control drag thing it is an easy way to connect your UI and your code. Glad you got it solved